# How to make koa ctx.throw() use application/json rather than text/plain

Tags: javascript, koa

I have made a custom error handler for my koa app which works beautifully (except for one sticking point) - using `ctx.throw()` means any stacktrace is emitted to the server logs and also any custom error message is sent in the response.

The *one* problem is that `Content-Type` header is `text/plain` but I really need it to be `application/json`.

`app.js`:

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser';
import logger from 'koa-morgan';

import authentication from './middleware/authentication';
import config from './config';
import errorHandler from './middleware/error-handler';
import notificationsRoutes from './routes/notifications';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(logger(config.logLevel));
app.use(authentication);
app.use(notificationsRoutes.routes());

export default app;
```

`error-handler.js`:

```
export default async (ctx, next) => {
  return next().catch(({ statusCode, message }) => {
    ctx.throw(statusCode, JSON.stringify({ message }));
  });
};
```

(I thought `(statusCode, JSON.stringify({ message }));` might coerce the response into `application/json` but it doesn't.

I have googled to no avail. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to modify the `error-handler` to produce the desired result. Works really well - stack traces are emitted to server logs and the first line of that message becomes the `message` in the response body. The latter might be considered a downside by some but it depends what you're after.

`error-handler.js`:

```
export default async (ctx, next) => {
  return next().catch(err => {
    const { statusCode, message } = err;

    ctx.type = 'json';
    ctx.status = statusCode || 500;
    ctx.body = {
      status: 'error',
      message
    };

    ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);
  });
};
```

Found this and used it for reference: https://github.com/koajs/examples/blob/master/errors/app.js

It's worth mentioning that this custom error - `ServerError.js` - is used in the app; that's why `ctx.status = statusCode || 500` - `statusCode` is provided by `ServerError` when used, but for non-custom errors that are thrown, `statusCode` comes through to `error-handler.js` as `undefined` so `|| 500` is needed.

`ServerError.js`:

```
export class ServerError extends Error {
  constructor(statusCode, message) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
}
```

(usage: `throw new ServerError(400, 'my informative error message');`)

Don't have any `catch` blocks in any of your middlewares and the error will propagate all the way up to your top `errorHandler` middleware in `app.js` (which is what you want to happen).

Custom error handling in koa seems to generate many different opinions but this seems to work well for us for now.

Comment: Have tried this method, using node request only get an "Internal Server Error" from the res.body , using Superkoa to run the test, and the res.body is still the entire string output, instead of a JSON object. Is there any way to capture the payload in an object for the client to undersand what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add Error handler middleware

```js
  server.use(async function jsonErrorHandler(ctx, next)  {
    try {
      await next();
    } catch (err: any) {
      ctx.status = err.status || err.statusCode || 500;
      ctx.body = { message: err };
      ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);
    }
  });
```

then throw the error like this:

```js
export async function usersIssuesHandler(context: Context) {
    ....
    context.throw('some error here',500);
}
```